# Margin not showing with 100% width & height

Tags: height, width, media

I was trying to build myself a portfolio site. When I thought I was about to finish building the basic template, the margin and media queries stuff totally drove me crazy.
Here is my temporarily hosted domain, [www.kenlyxu.com/portfolio_new](http://www.kenlyxu.com/portfolio_new)

I made the pages fit to whatever browser size by using

```
html, body {   
     margin:0; 
     padding:0; 
     width:100%; 
     height:100%;
```

I'm trying to make 10px margin on all side and on every page so that I use this container.

```
#thecontainer {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #f29e28;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

#workcontainer {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #f29e28;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

I hope the end result would be like orange background with white margins on all sides. When seeing my site on the desktop, the margin-right and margin-bottom not showing. They only show when I use width: 98.5%;

Also, the orange background color should expand according to the size of browser. On the iPhone 5 portrait view, the orange background does not extent the bottom part. I tried to use some standard media queries for it, but I don't know what values should I give to each of the mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Position:fixed;
```

in

```
 # thethecontainer
```

now your code looks like

```
#thecontainer {
margin: 10px;
background-color: #f29e28;
height: 98%;
position:fixed;
width: 98.5%;
}
```

Comment: Here is a plunker with above suggestion.
http://plnkr.co/edit/27OzvVx0rulhUZFehw3F?p=preview